# Calling a generator object returns the error 'TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable'

Tags: python, pytest

I have a `Generate` function which I am using to generate some user data. Then passing it to a pytest fixture for use in a testcase.

However when I try to run it. I am getting `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`.

I am calling a function the returns the dictionary, and not the dictionary itself. Why am I receiving this error?

`Generate.py`:

```
class Generate(object):
    def __init__(self):
        fake = Faker()

        self.user = {
            "Username": fake.name().split(' ', 1)[0],
            "Email Address": fake.email(),
            "Password": fake.word(),
            "Todo": fake.word()
        }

    def user(self):
        new_user = self.user
        return new_user
```

`conftest.py`:

```
@pytest.fixture
def user():
    generator = Generate()
    user = generator.user()
    yield user
```

Comment: Note: the `user()` function as defined here will always return the same mutable object. I assume that the `new_user = self.user` line is intended to make a copy? If so, you need to call the `.copy` method, or use `copy.copy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing `generator.user`, you are referencing the `user` attribute of your class (that you defined with `self.user=...`). This is indeed a dictionary. This is hiding the method you also called `user`. You should probably rename one of the two, for example:

```py
def GetUser(self):
    new_user = self.user
    return new_user
```